# Face detection and recognition code is not working in C# with Emgu CV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, face-detection, face-recognition

I am trying to implement face detection and recognition system using Emgu CV.
I got an already implemented project.
[multiple-face-detection-and-recognition-in-real](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239849/Multiple-face-detection-and-recognition-in-real)
Here is the link where I got the project.

1. I have downloaded and install Emgu CV library as mentioned in this tutorial : 
   [EmguCv / OpenCV Installation Tutorial ( windows ) | EmguCv Camera Application Part 1 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpPvkeKgsaQ)
2. I have opened this project in visual studio 2017 and also follow all the steps mentioned in the project(first) link.
3. But when I am running my project, the camera of my laptop is indicating that it is on but I am unable to see anything on the image-grabber area.
4. I am using windows 10 64bit. and latest Emgu CV.
   and my laptop camera is in working condition I have tested it example projects of Emgu CV lib.
   If anyone has any solution please help me
   Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EmguCv library which is used in that example is outdated and it is not compatible. I tried with the latest EmguCv library and it is working now.

Comment: I'm in your same situation. Can you share your project?

Comment: @puntanet, I have resolved this issue by using the latest EmguCv library but some functions are missing in this library it seems. So I could not complete the project